# Adding a JFFS2 file system to QEMU

Tags: qemu, flash-memory, petalinux

I am trying to set up a development environment using QEMU to emulate a Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC ZCU102. I have a Petalinux image that I am able to run with QEMU and now I want to pass in and mount file system containing an executable and required .so files that I made with mkfs.jffs2. I tried passing several different arguments to QEMU through the petalinux-boot --qemu command, but I have never been able to find the file system after booting into Linux.

Arguments I've tried:

```
-drive file=/PATH/TO/JFFS2/FILESYSTEM,format=raw,if=pflash,id=foo,unit=1

-drive file=/PATH/TO/JFFS2/FILESYSTEM,format=raw,if=mtd,id=foo

-device loader,file=/PATH/TO/JFFS2/FILESYSTEM,addr=0x4240000

-drive file=/PATH/TO/JFFS2/FILESYSTEM,format=raw,id=foo -device nand,drive=foo
```

I admit that I do not have any real experience with QEMU and my googling lead to the unsuccessful attempts above, so this post may be lacking some important details I am not aware of, if you need any additional information please let me know and I will provide it.

Thank you